# subset matrix by more than one thing fast

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix I would like to subset quickly using two criteria. 1) the colnames match the rownames and 2) the value in one matrix is FALSE

```
m
  [,1]
A    1
B    2
C    3
D    4
E    5

tf
        E     B     A
[1,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

the output should be

```
m2
  [,1]
E    5
B    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is only a single row for 'tf', when we subset the logical matrix by negating, it results in a named `vector` as subsetting (`[`) by default is `drop=TRUE`.  Extract the `names` from the `vector` and use it as row index to subset the 'm'.  Here, we can use `drop=FALSE` as there is only a single column in 'm'.

```
m[names(tf[,!tf]), , drop=FALSE]
#   [,1]
#E    5
#B    2
```

#### data

```
m <- matrix(1:5, nrow=5, 1, dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:5], NULL))
tf <- matrix(c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), ncol=3, dimnames=list(NULL, c("E", "B", "A")))
```